# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed_query' using Langchain FAISS vectorstore

Tags: langchain, faiss, vectorstore

I'm following AWS Bedrock workshop here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-bedrock-workshop/blob/main/03_QuestionAnswering/01_qa_w_rag_claude.ipynb.  Everything is working fine until I go to the following:

```
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.indexes.vectorstore import VectorStoreIndexWrapper

vectorstore_faiss = FAISS.from_documents(
    docs,
    bedrock_embeddings,
)

wrapper_store_faiss = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=vectorstore_faiss)
```

```
query = """Is it possible that I get sentenced to jail due to failure in filings?"""

query_embedding = vectorstore_faiss.embedding_function.embed_query(query)
```

I get the following error on the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed_query'
```

I get the following error on the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed_query'
```

Comment: What version of `langchain` and `langchain-community` are you using? The AWS tutorial may be out of date in terms of the LangChain API. The error indicates that a function (`Callable`) was passed to the vector store's embedding function, but it should be an `Embeddings` object. Support for `Callable` will be deprecated.

Comment: Seems to me that this was broken with a new update? I'm getting the same error with activeloop data lake too...

Comment: thanks.  so I tried running this instead but now get the following:    ----> 1 query_embedding = vectorstore_faiss.embeddings.embed_query(query)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'embed_query'